# Jetpack Compose: Center Icon or Trailing elements in a ListItem

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack-compose-list

I'm trying to center the icon and trailing elements vertically using a ListItem. I'm not sure if it is possible or I need to drop the ListItem and use a combination of column/row instead.

[image]

I'm using something like:

```
ListItem(
    Modifier.clickable(onClick = onClick),
    icon = {
        Box(
           modifier = Modifier.fillMaxHeight(), contentAlignment = ALignment.Center
        ) {
            Text(
                text = dateUtil.formatTime(item.startTime),
                style = TextStyle(
                    color = SnyDarkBlue,
                    fontSize = 14.sp,
                    fontFamily = oswaldFamily,
                    fontWeight = FontWeight.Bold,
                    letterSpacing = (-0.25).sp,
                ),
            )
        }
    },
```

thanks in advance!

Comment: Sure it is possible to align the icon in the vertical center.

Comment: @LiemVo and do you know how to do it?

Comment: You are almost there. From your code just update the value of `contentAlignment` to `Alignment.Center` then it work without issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can center both the icon and text sections using a Column:

```
ListItem(
    modifier = Modifier
        .fillMaxWidth()
        .requiredHeight(50.dp)
        .background(color = Color.Gray),
    icon = {
        Column(
            modifier = Modifier
                .fillMaxHeight(), verticalArrangement = Arrangement.Center
        ) {
            Text(
                text = "06:00 PM"
            )
        }
    },
    text = {
        Column(
            modifier = Modifier
                .fillMaxHeight(), verticalArrangement = Arrangement.Center
        ) {
            Text("Your item text goes here")
        }
    },
)
```

Comment: Oh I see what I was missing, I need to set the static height **requiredHeight(50.dp)**, makes sense. Thanks @Johann

Comment: So it's not possible to center the icon or the trailing view without requiring a fixed height for the entire row?