# How to customize the alignment of leadingContent and trailingContent of androidx.compose.material3.ListItem?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, listitem, android-jetpack-compose-material3

Given the following `androidx.compose.material3.ListItem` code snippet ...

```
ListItem(
    leadingContent = {
        LeadingIcon()
    },
    trailingContent = {
        TrailingIcon()
    },
    overlineText = {
        Text(
            text = item.text,
        )
    },
    headlineText = {
        Text(
            text = item.title,
            overflow = Ellipsis,
            maxLines = 1,
        )
    },
    supportingText = {
        if (item.subtitle.isNotEmpty()) {
            Text(
                text = item.subtitle,
                overflow = Ellipsis,
                maxLines = 1,
            )
        }
    }
)
```

Is there a way to vertically center the leading and trailing content/icons?
It would also be desired that the item shrinks its height if no `subtitle` is given. The icons should then still be centered.

## Related

- [Can ListItem leadingContent be top aligned in Jetpack Compose Material3?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73935936/can-listitem-leadingcontent-be-top-aligned-in-jetpack-compose-material3)
- https://m3.material.io/components/lists/specs#583e3432-0dc0-4a18-bfb4-a0924f67891b
- [Jetpack Compose: Center Icon or Trailing elements in a ListItem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69993459/jetpack-compose-center-icon-or-trailing-elements-in-a-listitem)

Comment: Do you accept the possibility of using a fixed height of the ListItem, or do you need the ability to change the height flexibly?

Comment: I would prefer to let the `ListItem` wrap its content.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this looks the best, but you could try setting two fixed heights for the content with `item.subtitle` and without `item.subtitle`, and wrap the `Icon` in a `Column` and set the alignment to center:

```
ListItem(
    modifier = Modifier.height(
        if (item.subtitle.isNotEmpty()) 84.dp else 64.dp
    ),
    leadingContent = {
        Column(
            modifier = Modifier.fillMaxHeight(),
            verticalArrangement = Arrangement.Center
        ) {
            LeadingIcon()
        }
    },
    trailingContent = {
        Column(
            modifier = Modifier.fillMaxHeight(),
            verticalArrangement = Arrangement.Center
        ) {
            TrailingIcon()
        }
    },
    ...
)
```